# how to make one side without container restrictions?

Tags: html, css

By design, I have a site container. I need to create one block so that there are no container restrictions on the right, but they are on the left.
On the design below, the image should be pressed to the right edge of the page, and the container limits should be on the left.
How can I make such a block?
My HTML:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1260px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.main-screen {
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #dedde2 0%, #e3e6ed 44.29%, #dde6ef 100%);
}

.main-screen-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 118px;
}
```

```html
<section class="main-screen">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="main-screen-content">
            <div class="main-screen-title">
                <h1>
                    Replace awkward lab visits with at-home <span class="blue-text-style">STI testing</span> and
                    <span class="orange-text-style">treatment</span>.
                </h1>
                <div class="site-button main-screen-button">
                    <button class="text-button">
                        Get started
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-screen-img">
                <img src="./img/main-screen-img.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Could you add a runnable code snippet of what you have achieved so far?

Comment: i added my html and css code. But now I have an image in a container, and not pressed to the right edge of the site

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/ - this can be applied only on one side instead of both, as well.

Comment: (for your specific case) you could also set that image as a background-image for your `main-screen` with `background-position: right`

Comment: Setting an image as a background is not a good solution for responsiveness in this case.

Comment: @user_756 Do you have a link to the image you will be using?

Comment: @user_756  why do you think it's not a good solution for responsiveness? You can always use `@media` rules for responsiveness - you can do whatever you want with that background for any device.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to add the blue bg with the image as a single image and add it as a background. But I could see in the comment section this method is not suitable for your need.

Alternative way,
How about adding blue color as a background to the main section And positioning the person image using position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; to the section.